# rails 3 html_safe confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I achieve this?

In a controller

```
@arr = ["<one>", "<two>"]
```

In a view (haml)

```
= @arr.join("<br>")
```

As you guess, `"<br>"` shouldn't be escaped. So the result would be like the following.

```
&lt;one%gt;<br>&lt;two%gt;
```

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could roll your own:

```
arr = ["<one>", "<two>"]
''.html_safe.tap {|x|
  arr.each_with_index { |el, ix|
    x << el
    x << raw("<br/>") if ix < arr.size-1
  }
}
```

Also look at the [Array.join code in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1a73407b8506b548a5343c66c16897140203472e)

Comment: Wow. This is much more complex than I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Rails has this [built in.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-safe_join)

```
<%= safe_join(@arr, "<br />".html_safe) %>
```

Comment: might be obvious, but worth noting this only works in the view.